# Show the order of $G\times H$ is equal to $lcm(ord(g), ord(h))$

Tags: abstract-algebra

### Problem:

Let $(G,\cdot)$ and $(H,*)$ be groups with identities $e$ and $\bar e$ respectively. Let $U = G\times H$ and define $\circ$ on $U$ by $(g_1,h_1)\circ (g_2,h_2)=(g_1\cdot g_2, h_1*h_2)$. Then $(U,\circ )$ is a group with identity $(e, \bar e).$

Let $x=(g,h)\in U$ and suppose $ord(g)=k$, $ord(h)=l$. Let $j=lcm(k,l).$ Show $ord(x)=j$.

So we have $(g,h)^u = (g^u,h^u)$   $\forall u\in \mathbb{Z}$

### Attempted solution:

My strategy is that I want to show that $x^j = (e, \bar e ) \Rightarrow ord(x)\leq j$. Then I want to show $ord(x)\geq j$

I am having a hard time arguing formally that the Cartesian product of two sets $A$ and $B$ with order, say $m$ and $n$, has $m\times n$ elements -- that is, $ord(A\times B)=ord(A)\times ord(B)$. I think this would help me show that $(g,h)^u = (g,h)^j =(g^j,h^j)=(e,\bar e)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $j = \operatorname{lcm}(k,l)$, then $k$ divides $j$ and $l$ divides $j$. Thus $g^j = (g^k)^{j/k} = e^{j/k} = e$ and $h^j = (h^l)^{j/l} = (\bar{e})^{j/l} = \bar{e}$. So $x^j = (e,\bar{e})$ and $\operatorname{ord}(x)$ divides $j$. On the other hand, letting $m = \operatorname{ord}(x)$, $x^m = (e,\bar{e})$, which implies $g^m = e$ and $h^m = \bar{e}$. Since $g^m = e$, then $k$ divides $m$; since $h^m = \bar{e}$, then $l$ divides $m$. Therefore $\operatorname{lcm}(k,l)$ divides $m$, i.e., $j$ divides $m$. Therefore $j = m = \operatorname{ord}(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $j$ is a multiple of $k$ and $l$, $j=mk$ and $j=nl$ for some $m,n$.

$x^j=(g^j, h^j)=(g^{km}, h^{ln})=(e^m, \bar e^n)=(e,\bar e)$ so $ord(x)\le j$

If we can show that the order of $x$ is also a multiple of both $k$ and $l$ then we will have established that $ord(x)\ge j$ and we will be done.

Let $p=ord(x)$.

Then, by Euclid's theorem, $p=qk+r$ where $r\lt k$.

$g^p=e=g^{qk+r}=g^{qk}g^r=e^qg^r=g^r$

$\therefore$ $g^r=e$ but $r\lt k=ord(g)$ so $r=0$

$\therefore$, $p=qk$ so $p$ is a multiple of the order of $g$

A similar argument shows that $p$ is a multiple of the order of $h$ so $p\ge lcm(k,l)=j$

Therefore, the order of (g,h) is the least common multiple of the order of $g$ and the order of $h$

Answer (score 1):

By definition. a finite set $A$ has order $m$ if there exists a bijection:

$f: A \to \{1,2,\dots, m\}$ and similarly with $B$, there is a bijection:

$g: B \to \{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Define $h: A \times B \to \{1,2,\dots,mn\}$ by:

$h(a,b) = f(a) + m(g(b) - 1)$.

It's not hard to see this is a bijection:

if $h(a,b) = h(a',b')$, then $h(a,b) \equiv h(a',b') \text{ (mod }m)$

so that $f(a) = f(a')$ (since $1 \leq f(a),f(a') \leq m$, the remainder mod $m$ is unique), and thus $g(b) = g(b')$, and $h$ is injective.

On the other hand, writing $k \in \{1,2,\dots, mn\}$ as $k = mq + r$ we see that if $r \neq 0$ we have $a \in A$ with $f(a) = r$, and $b \in B$ with $g(b) = q + 1$ ($q$ is limited to values between $0$ and $n-1$), so:

$h(a,b) = f(a) + m(g(b) - 1) = r + m(q + 1 - 1) = mq + r = k$.

If $r = 0$, choose the $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = m$, and the $b \in B$ such that $g(b) = q$, and:

$h(a,b) = f(a) + m(g(b) - 1) = m + m(q - 1) = m + qm - m = qm = k$.

Thus, $h$ is surjective.

---

In your "proof proper" you actually have an easier time of it:

If $g^k = e$ and $h^l = \overline{e}$, then since both $k,m$ divide $j = \text{lcm}(k,l)$  it is immediate that:

$(g,h)^j = (g^j,h^j) = (e,\overline{e}) = e_{G\times H}$.

To finish, it's easier to use this lemma:

If $G$ is a group and $g \in G$ has order $m$, then for $t > 0$, if $g^t = e$, then $m|t$.

Since $m$ is minimal amongst all positive integers $k$ with $g^k = e$, we have $t \geq m$. Writing $t = qm + r$, with $0 \leq r < m$, we have:

$e = g^t = (g^{qm})(g^r) = (g^m)^q(g^r) = (e^q)(g^r) = g^r$.

If $r \neq 0$, this violates the minimality of $m$, so $r = 0$, that is $t = qm$, so $m$ divides $t$.

Thus the order of $(g,h)$ is a common multiple of $k,l$, but $j$ is the least such multiple, and we are done.